# How can I upload PDF file in firebase storage and generate download URL and save firebase using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I tried below the code but getting issues:

> Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
  withData: true
);

if (result != null) {
  Uint8List? fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  String fileName = result.files.first.name;

  // Upload PDF file
  TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await storage.ref('CV/$fileName').putData(fileBytes!);
  String pdfUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

  print('pdf url: $pdfUrl');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the `fileBytes` variable was null at runtime and you're using the null check operator on it.

The reason for the null bytes from the picked file is because by default, the byte data is not returned from the [pickFiles](https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/FilePicker/pickFiles.html) method (except for web). You need to set `withData` to `true` and the null error should disappear.

> If withData is set, picked files will have its byte data immediately
> available on memory as Uint8List which can be useful if you are
> picking it for server upload or similar. However, have in mind that
> enabling this on IO (iOS & Android) may result in out of memory issues
> if you allow multiple picks or pick huge files. Use withReadStream
> instead. Defaults to true on web, false otherwise.
>
> [Source](https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/FilePicker/pickFiles.html#:%7E:text=If%20withData%20is,web%2C%20false%20otherwise.)

Update your code to this:

```dart
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  type: FileType.custom,
  allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
  withData: true
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working.  For generating PDF download URL: 
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await storage.ref('CV/$fileName').putData(fileBytes!);
String pdfUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();